# Create fishnet of irregular polygon study area

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector-grid

I would like to create a fishnet (grid of 150x150m cells) for a study area (irregular shaped polygon). However, the Create Fishnet tool creates a fishnet representing the full extent of the study area (max/min long/lat) and I only need grid cells within the study area.

I can't seem to select by location (freezes) and then create layer from selected features that intersect the study area polygon. The # of grid cells is possibly too large (study area is ~440,000 km2, fishnet includes 30 million features).

Is there some other way to limit the Create Fishnet tool to only create polygon grid cells within the study area boundary?

Comment: Your methodology for subset is correct.  Maybe you should focus on the  error.  Please **edit** the question to include the exact number of fishnet features and an indication of the complexity of the study area polygon.

Comment: Once your fishnet is up to 30m features, you should really be using raster representation, then convert to vector for individual pixels when vector modeling is required.

Comment: Thanks Vince. Do you know if there is a thread somewhere with instruction for how to convert raster to vector grid cells?

Comment: Raster to Polygon is the tool, but only if you've got a few non-neighboring pixels in a sea of NODATA.  Otherwise you'll see the same "freeze" as ArcGIS attempts to execute the billions (or even trillions) of instructions you've requested.

Comment: But I am not sure I understand how to instruct the tool so it will convert the raster to a vector grid, and not just a vector boundary...?

Comment: Exactly.  The answer is to not use too-small fishnet cells (15km,  not 0.15km).